# Pandas scatter plot series with total mean of series as line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've plotted successfully a scatter plot of a series.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

tips = pd.DataFrame([20, 10, 50, 60, 90, 20, 30, 15, 75, 35], columns = ['Tips'])
tips.index += 1
tips.index.name = 'Meals'

tips.reset_index().plot.scatter(x=tips.index.name, y='Tips', label='Tip Amount')
```

[image]

Now I'm trying to plot the average of the series (40.5) as a flat line , but not being able to do so.

Here is the code attempt for the same

```
ax = tips.mean().plot()
tips.reset_index().plot.scatter(x=tips.index.name, y='Tips', label='Tip Amount', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [axhline()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-axhline) function

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = pd.DataFrame([20, 10, 50, 60, 90, 20, 30, 15, 75, 35], columns = ['Tips'])
tips.index += 1
tips.index.name = 'Meals'

plot = tips.reset_index().plot.scatter(x=tips.index.name, y='Tips', label='Tip Amount')
plot.axhline(tips.mean()[0])
```